# SDL Event - can't get the sprite to move down or right

Tags: c++, events, sdl

I have stumbled upon a problem where when I move my sprite through the use of the arrow keys- it will only move up or left but when I try to move him right or down the screen, it won't move at all.

I have tried by replacing in the event loop: "SDLK_RIGHT:" to the same as the SDLK_LEFT case is now when that does work and it works perfect, the movement is still going left since the code says it, but as soon as I try to remove the negative number it doesn't move.

What I know floats should accept positive values as well :/

Code of the method:

```
    // Updates the sprites position in the game
void Sprite::tick( SDL_Event event )
{       

        if( event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN )
        {
            switch( event.key.keysym.sym )
            {
            case SDLK_LEFT:
                {
                    velocityX = -0.1f;
                    break;
                }
            case SDLK_RIGHT:
                {
                    velocityX = 0.5f;
                    break;
                }
            case SDLK_UP:
                {
                    velocityY = -0.1f;
                    break;
                }
            case SDLK_DOWN:
                {
                    velocityY = 0.5f;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if( event.type == SDL_KEYUP )
        {
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
            {
            case SDLK_LEFT: velocityX = 0.0f; break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT: velocityX = 0.0f; break;
            case SDLK_UP: velocityY = 0.0f; break;
            case SDLK_DOWN: velocityY = 0.0f; break;
            default: break;
            }
        }


    if(alive)
    {
        setBoundingbox(x_pos, y_pos, width, height);

//      if( inMidAir )
    //  {
        //  velocityX += 0.1f;
        //}


        x_pos += velocityX;

        if( ( x_pos < 0 ) || ( x_pos + width > 870 ))
        {
            x_pos -= velocityX;
        }

        y_pos += velocityY;

        if( ( y_pos < 0 ) || ( y_pos + height > 480 ) )
        {
            y_pos -= velocityY;
        }

    }// End of alive statement

}
```

and the event loop:

```
// Game loop
while( quit == false )
{
    while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ))
    {
        player.tick( event );
if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
        {
            quit = true;
        }

    }

    applySurface(0, 0, background, screen);
    applySurface(player.get_xpos(), player.get_ypos(), 
        player.get_Surface(), screen);
    SDL_Flip(screen);
}
```

I hope someone can see why I can't move as I want

Comment: **1.** Have you checked that the `if ... (x_pos + width > 870)` does not trigger? **2.** Can you show the definition of `x_pos`, `y_pos`, `velocityX`, `velocityY`, `get_xpos()` and `get_ypos()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `x_pos` and `y_pos` are integers, then subtracting a small `float` from them (even `0.1f`) is roughly equivalent to subtracting 1, as truncating back to an `int` effectively rounds down.

That is, if `x_pos` equals 100, then `100 - 0.1f` will evaluate to `99.9f`, but get truncated to `99` as an `int`.

But, when you try to move to the right, you have `100 + 0.5f`, which evaluates to `100.5f`, but gets truncated back to `100` as an `int`.

That's why you can move up and to the left (both decreasing coordinates), but not down or to the right (increasing coordinates).

You need to make your types consistent.

Comment: Thanks alot, i feel stupid I didnt see that simple math error... But is there a reason It only moves one step at the time for an example, if I press up it moves up abit then nothing, i gotta press up repeatedly for it to move :/

Comment: @sandmaster: You should add the velocity values to you player position each frame. In the key up event you should change the velocity with the inverted values of your key down event. Make sure to multiply it with the frametime in some way to make the movement speed independent of the framerate.

Comment: @Skalli: Thanks alot, I got it fixed by splitting the method up into 2 methods instead- one to handle events and one to update the position, now i really need to get a fps limit hehe goes way to fast :)

Comment: @sandmaster: That's why you have to measure the frametime. If you have something like PositionX += VelocityX * FrametimeInSeconds the object moves with constant speed, independent of the framerate. A common pitfall is to many FPS (leading to FrameTimeInSeconds becoming 0 which equals no movement). This can be avoided by using high precision timer and decimals. Btw.: It's common to have one method to render and one method to do the movement, so you're on the right track.

Comment: I have now implemented a fps timer to stop the sprite to move too fast, problem I found is that it "jumps" after a while, it doesnt seem to speed up and thats fine, but it seems wierd that when i hold the key down the sprite moves slowly abit and then instantly moves 70% of the screen. I can't find where the code would do something like that, tried lowering the fps to 1 and thats where i saw it.

Comment: @sandmaster: Well, if you show 1 FPS is it moving the same distance in this second and frame as when you have 60 FPS? THe idea behind is, no matter how many frames you show, it moves the same distance in the same time. It makes jumps of course, when you move fast and have few frames.

Comment: @sandmaster : At 1FPS I would expect it to look jumpy.  As Skalli suggests, if you specify your velocities in some unit like pixels per second, then if you only have 1 FPS, you will jump by however many pixels every second.

Comment: @skalli: Yea, That I can understand, sorry for not responding but got it solved, the problem in my case was that I had started the timer fps 1 line wrong so it became very wrong, but it works as it should now. Thanks for all the help :)